# How can I ensure the binary consistency of the serialport (npm module)?

Tags: node.js, npm, binary, node-serialport

I currently have a requirement to ensure the binary consistency of my project, but there is a problem. The rest of my project has been guaranteed, except for the `serialport` module, every time I use `npm install`, it will recompile, resulting in a binary difference, the timestamp difference has been eliminated, but there is a string of code Unable to eliminate, after verification, this is caused by a compile option, as shown below:

```
<GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
```

It is in the file `serialport.vcxproj`, its value is changed to false. But since every time you use `npm install`, you will download the `serialport` from the official repository and then compile it automatically, so you can't find an improvement.
Is there any other way to eliminate the binary difference here?

[image]

Comment: <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>

Comment: The docs seem to indicate the it uses prebuilt binaries on Windows, unless you do `npm install serialport --build-from-source`. How are you installing the module?

Comment: In my project there is a file `package.json` that contains the dependencies I need, one of which is the `serialport`, I used the command `npm install` directly during installation.